# C++ Deleting two dimensional dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-allocation

I have a problem with two dimensional dynamically allocated array I'm using in my code. Everything works fine until my program tries to call the destructor of my `tablica2D` object. I get a runtime error "HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED" when my program gets to the last `delete[] tab` command. Does this mean that the loop preceding it already deallocates all of memory assigned to `tab`? I was under the impression that to deallocate all of dynamically assigned memory there needs to be one `delete` command for each `new` command. Or is something else causing this error?

Here is the code of the class that's causing me trouble:

```
class tablica2D
{
    static const int k = 2;
    int n, m;
    string **tab;
public:
    tablica2D(int n, int m)
    {
        this->n = n;
        this->m = m;

        tab = new string*[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            tab[i] = new string[m];
        }
    }
    string* operator [](int n)
    {
        return tab[n];
    }
    static const bool compareRows(const string* i, const string* j)
    {
        int x = atoi(i[k].c_str());
        int y = atoi(j[k].c_str());
        return x > y;
    }
    void sort()
    {
        std::sort(tab, tab + n, compareRows);
    }
    ~tablica2D()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            delete[] tab[i];
        }
        delete[] tab;
    }
};
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: Why for heaven'
s sake you're struggling with memory management on your own, where it's all perfectly available with [standard c++ containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [dynamic memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Perhaps it's an assignment.

Comment: @RawN There seems to be an epidemic of teachers assigning things like this, and never mentioning to the student all that's required to implement this properly.  For example, issues such as the "rule of 3", which the OP failed to implement.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No doubt about that. I've seen my fair share of that nonsense and pseudoscience here in SE Europe. What they 'teach' here could be easily labeled as crime.

Comment: @RawN What winds up happening is that the student creates something that is buggy, but gets a passing grade anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong variable in your `new` loop, and additionally creating a 3d array instead of a 2d array:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    //                 ^^, should be n
    {
        tab[i] = new string[m];
        //                 ^^^
        // should be new string, not new string[m]
    }
```

vs:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    //                 ^^, this one is correct
    {
        delete[] tab[i];
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `n` instead of `m`?

Comment: Actually it should also be n in the first loop, but after this change everything works. I missed this because I used m > n in my tests so my array had extra empty rows but could fit everything I tried to put inside. Thanks for a fast response.

Comment: @Kurigalzu Even with this change, your `tablica2D` class is easily broken by a two line main() program.  `{ tablica2D t1(10, 10); tablica2D t2 = t1; }`  You failed to implement the "rule of 3" in your class.

Answer (score 0):

If I need a C-like 2D array I always use:

```
type **myarr = new type*[X];
myarr[0] = new type[X*Y];
for (int i = 1; i < X; i++) {
    myarr[i] = myarr[0] + i * Y;
}
```

For usage:

```
myarr[x][y]
```

Then for freeing:

```
delete[] myarr[0];
delete[] myarr;
```

The same, with some little effort, can be applied for N-dimentional array.